# Java - Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

When running a program via Eclipse is it possible to provide command like arguments to be stored in the String[] args as you can on the command line?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373328/invoking-java-main-method-with-parameters-from-eclipse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just specify those arguments in the Run configuration (Arguments tab) menu of your project.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

If you click on the arrow next to the "Run" button, you can open the Run Configurations menu. You can specify both Program Arguments (which are passed into the args[] parameter to your main method) as well as VM Arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can specify it as part of the run configuration for a project

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Click on Run - Run configurations... Then select your run configuration, select the Arguments tab, and enter arguments in the Arguments text area.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The easiest way is to right-click on the class you want to run and select

```
Run As->Run Configurations
```

There is a tab to add arguments.

Answer (score 1):

In `Run configuuration` you can give it here at this location.

[image]